# jQuery not working after form validation failure

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the form below and I have a jquery snippetwhich adds `$` to the beginning of the user's input whether they type it or not.

If i submit the form and it fails on validation, my jquery snippet no longer works to prepend the `$` to the user's input.

Why does this not work after form validation?

```
<h:form id="add">

    <h:outputLabel for="startDate" value="Start Date" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:message for="startDate" />
        <p:calendar value="#{fundingBacker.startDate}" id="startDate" mode="popup" navigator="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Start Date is required" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:outputLabel for="totalCost" value="Total Cost" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:message for="totalCost" />
    <p:inputText value="#{fundingBacker.totalCost}" id="totalCost" styleClass="currency">
        <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" groupingUsed="#{true}" maxFractionDigits="0" type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
    </p:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Add Grant" type="submit"  actionListener="#{fundingBacker.add}"  />
</h:form>
```

jQuery snippet

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.currency').on('keyup', function() {
        console.log('keyup');
        if($(this).val().indexOf('$') == -1) {
            $(this).val('$'+$(this).val()); 
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is the validation code

Comment: It's the required attribute on the startDate

Comment: Do you validate server side or client side? Any error in the javascript console?

Comment: @HarryFink You must not be familiar with JSF. The validation is `required="true" requiredMessage="Start Date is required"`

Comment: Yes, I don't know JSF. What html does it generate? When you click the submit button, does it sends the data to the server or validates it client side before posting?

Comment: The cause is not visible in the code posted so far. Didn't you oversimplify the code a bit too much and did you remove `update="@form"` from the command button orso? I'm at least not seeing any way how you make the validation messages to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(document).ready()` is fired during page load, when the HTML DOM is ready populating. However, you're most likely ajax-updating the form on submit (your current code does not show that, but this way the validation messages would never show up, surely you must be doing this somewhere). When you ajax-udpate the form, then JavaScript has replaced the form elements in the HTML DOM tree with new elements from the ajax response. However, the `$(document).ready()` doesn't run after an ajax update and hence those new elements are never applied with the keyup handler.

There are basically 2 solutions:

1. Re-run the code in `$(document).ready()` on complete of ajax request.

   E.g.

   ```html
   <p:commandButton ... oncomplete="applyCurrencyOnKeyup()" />
   ```

   with

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
       applyCurrencyOnKeyup();
   });

   function applyCurrencyOnKeyup() {
       $('.currency').on('keyup', function() {
           if($(this).val().indexOf('$') == -1) {
               $(this).val('$'+$(this).val()); 
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   ---
2. Rewrite `$(document).ready()` as [`$(document).on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

   ```js
   $(document).on("keyup", ".currency", function() {
       if($(this).val().indexOf('$') == -1) {
           $(this).val('$'+$(this).val()); 
       }
   });
   ```

   *(no, no need to wrap that up in a document ready)*

Comment: I went with option 2. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: You're welcome. In future questions, please be careful that you post a real SSCCE. Even if you simplify the code while preparing the question, you should re-test it at your actual environment in order to avoid the risk that you oversimplified it and thus makes the question incorrect/unanswerable.